# Read input from popen() into char * in C

Tags: c, char, popen

I have a FILE pointer that contains input from popen(). I want to put all of the input into a char *str, but I don't know how to do this (new to C-programming).

```
void save_cmd(int fd) {
  char buf[100];
  char *str;
  FILE *ls;
  if (NULL == (ls = popen("ls", "r"))) {
    perror("popen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ls) != NULL) {
    //Don't know what to do here....
  }
  pclose(ls);
}
```

I guess I somehow have to concatenate inside the while loop, but how is this possible when I don't know the total size in advance (I want to save the whole result in char *str). If anyone have som pointers on how to do this I would be very grateful.

Comment: One thing you can do : use realloc function and then copy your new string into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so in your code you have captured a line into the `buf`.

now you want to have it all in the *str variable correct.

you need to allocate memory for it and then copy. here is an example:

```
void save_cmd(int fd) {
  char buf[100];
  char *str = NULL;
  char *temp = NULL;
  unsigned int size = 1;  // start with size of 1 to make room for null terminator
  unsigned int strlength;

  FILE *ls;
  if (NULL == (ls = popen("ls", "r"))) {
    perror("popen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ls) != NULL) {
    strlength = strlen(buf);
    temp = realloc(str, size + strlength);  // allocate room for the buf that gets appended
    if (temp == NULL) {
      // allocation error
    } else {
      str = temp;
    }
    strcpy(str + size - 1, buf);     // append buffer to str
    size += strlength; 
  }
  pclose(ls);
}
```

Comment: (1) Writing `ptr = realloc(ptr, new_size);` leaks memory on allocation failure; use `other = realloc(ptr, new_size); if (other != 0) ptr = other;`.  (2) Calculate `strlen(buf)` once. (3) Using `strcat()` leads to quadratic behaviour; keep a record of how long the string in `str` currently is, and then use `strcpy(str + len, buf); len += buflen;` (where `buflen = strlen(buf);` answers (2)).