# Does realloc need free operation when I use it for popen

Tags: c, string, pointers, popen, realloc

I have seen a post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932616/read-input-from-popen-into-char-in-c) where a user replies for the dynamic allocation of the popen output.

For convenience, I paste the code here.

```
void save_cmd(int fd) {


char buf[100];
  char *str = NULL;
  char *temp = NULL;
  unsigned int size = 1;  // start with size of 1 to make room for null terminator
  unsigned int strlength;

  FILE *ls;
  if (NULL == (ls = popen("ls", "r"))) {
    perror("popen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ls) != NULL) {
    strlength = strlen(buf);
    temp = realloc(str, size + strlength);  // allocate room for the buf that gets appended
    if (temp == NULL) {
      // allocation error
    } else {
      str = temp;
    }
    strcpy(str + size - 1, buf);     // append buffer to str
    size += strlength; 
  }
  pclose(ls);
}
```

In the code he uses realloc but I have two question about it.

1. When he uses `temp = realloc(str, size + strlength);` and in the if branch he assigns  `str = temp;`, the pointer temp needs to be deallocated using free?
2. Also for the str pointer, before leave the function, needs to be deallocated?

I have done a similar function but with little difference

```
static char* exec_commands(char* command)
{
    char buf[100];
    char *temp = NULL;
    char* output = NULL;
    unsigned int size = 1;  // start with size of 1 to make room for null terminator
    unsigned int strlength;

    FILE *ls;
    if (NULL == (ls = popen(command, "r"))) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ls) != NULL) 
    {
        strlength = strlen(buf);
        temp = realloc(output, size + strlength);  
        if (temp == NULL) {
        // allocation error
        } else {
            output = temp;
        }
        strcpy(output + size - 1, buf);     // append buffer to str
        size += strlength; 
    }
 
    pclose(ls);
    return output;
}

int main(void) {
   char command[1000] = "ls -lh /";
   char *output = NULL;
   
   output = exec_commands(command);
   printf("%s\n",output);
   free(output);

   return 0;
}
```

I think that in the post that I have linked there is a mistake, do you confirm?

thanks a lot

Comment: After `str = temp` freeing temp would free str, since they point to the same place.

Comment: If you allocate memory, with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`, then you must `free` it somewhere. Otherwise you have a memory leak.

Comment: Just some clarification that may make you come up with the answer yourself. `free(foo)` doesn't free the pointer `foo`. It frees the memory that `foo` points at.